# How can we produce the number x.y, where x and y are the two arguments or a function?

Tags: c, floating-point, hex

Given integer parameters `Num1` and `Num2`, how can a function return the number represented by the decimal numeral *x*.*y*, where *x* is the decimal numeral for `Num1` and `y` is the decimal numeral for `Num2`. For example, `CombineToFloat(1, 5)` should return 1.5; `CombineToFloat(11, 14)` should return 11.14, and `CombineToFloat(5, 10)` should return 5.10.

Comment: The title isn't just "weird", it's completely nonsensical. "the first second input after as a decimal after the first"?  HUH???

Comment: Re an edit, the result is 3 + (float)4 / 10;

Comment: @Weather Vane it was a typo

Comment: (a) What should the result be before 3 and 13? 3.13 (“3.” concatenated with “13”) or 4.3 (3 + 13/10)? (b) Will you ever want a result like 4.09? If so, how can `Num2` express that—if it is 9, you would get 4.9? (c) In most C implementations, `float` cannot represent 3.4 exactly. It only approximates it using powers of 2; the exact value would be 3.400000095367431640625 is that okay?

Comment: Re `sizeof Num2`: `sizeof` produces the number of bytes used for the type of an object—the number of bytes used to represent any value of that type. It does not change with the value; it is a property of the type. It looks like you were trying to get the number of decimal digits in `Num2`. That has to be calculated differently.

Comment: I edited your question to present it sensibly for decimal. Feel free to edit it further if the new text is not what you want.I removed the hexadecimal part—you can enter a new question for that, or you can update the text to add it, or you may be able to figure it out on your own now.

Comment: You could use `snprintf` to make the number in string form, and then `strtod` to convert it to a float

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For positive values of reasonable magnitude, subject to floating-point rounding:

```
float CombineToFloat(int Num1, int Num2)
{
    float PowerOf10 = 1;
    while (PowerOf10 <= Num2)
        PowerOf10 *= 10;
    return Num1 + Num2/PowerOf10;
}
```

For hexadecimal:

```
float CombineToFloat(int Num1, int Num2)
{
    float PowerOf16 = 1;
    while (PowerOf16 <= Num2)
        PowerOf16 *= 0x10;
    return Num1 + Num2/PowerOf16;
}
```

Comment: Edited. Also, I like it when while loops use curly brackets.

Comment: How can  I printf a hex without exponent

Comment: @noone: There is no standard format specifier for printing floating-point values in hexadecimal without an exponent. You could print to a buffer using `snprintf` with `%a` and then remove the exponent, or you could write your own formatting routine.

Comment: The second argument should probably be a string and not a number, otherwise you can't enter `1.05` for example

Comment: @user000001: OP was asked about this case in item (a) of my comment on the question and has not responded.